# How to enter password during runtime in Airflow

Tags: python, shell, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a script (RegisterKerbTicketAndOAuth.sh file) in remote cluster,

I am connecting to remote cluster from Airflow using ssh operator and logged in successfully which is successfull

Now the problem is, when I run the sh file like this

```
sh RegisterKerbTicketAndOAuth.sh  userID@azureprd.onmicrosoft.com
```

The above command will prompt for password twice at run time like this:

```
Enter password for this1:: XXXXXX
Enter password for this2:: XXXXXX
```

How do I pass my at run time in airflow

```
kinitCommandScript = """ 
sh RegisterKerbTicketAndOAuth.sh  userID@azureprd.onmicrosoft.com
"""
```

My Task Looks like this

```
kinitAuthentication = SSHOperator(
    ssh_hook = ConnectingToSSH, #SSHconnectionDetails
    task_id='GenerateTokenToRunDownstreamTasks',
    command= kinitCommandScript,
    #params={'my_param':NONFEDPASSWORD},
    dag=dag)
```

The above commented "#params" didnt worked. Can anyone suggest how to pass my password at run time for my shell script in airflow.

**Note**: Tried with BashOperator and its the same as above

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of how to run a shell script from some automated process, in general. The answer depends entirely on how your script is written and what commands/tools it calls. A common suggestion would be to use an environment variable to store the password. The `SSHOperator` supports this through its `environment` parameter. What environment variable you should use, or in fact whether this approach will work at all, 100% depends on what your script is doing.